# iPhone App: Check In using Facebook Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook, ios4

In my iPhone App I want to implement "Check in" feature (Facebook Places).

How can I check in using Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/checkins" withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

//parse our json
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *facebook_response =(NSMutableArray *)[fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];//[parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];   
[parser release];

NSMutableArray *feed =(NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response valueForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"%@",feed);
```

In the feed you can find the jason data of the places you have checked in..
If you get the "nil" data that means you have not checked in to any places so you have to first checkin to some places using your profile and FB.but if it is coming nil in that case only

and I am using the example from this referance :-https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

so adjust it as per your requirement

Comment: thanks for answer but Your answer is to get all post related to check in or  it is providing facility to Do "Check In" (Facebook places)

Comment: yes...you get all the post...and if you want to use check-in...then use post check-in method